# Why does the theme insert the comments section if I don't reset my custom WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, wp-reset-query

I have a bit of an odd situation. I have somehow solved it, but I'm trying to understand why my solution works.

I'm using TheBuilt, a theme that uses Visual Composer. I have extended Visual Composer with a custom element that I use to display a custom posts page (the main loop is not in use on that page, nor is any other custom loop). In order to build a posts object, I create a new WP_Query object that looks like this:

```
$categories_ids = '3,5' //examplary values
$query = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'cat' => $categories_ids,
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);

$posts = new WP_Query($query);
```

I then use the `$posts` object with `get_the_title`, `get_permalink()` et c. to build html blocks. However, when I added that element to a page, the theme rendered the comments section below the page content even though I had `Allow Comments` unchecked in the page options. I found that this does not happen when I evoke `wp_reset_query()` in my shortcode function before I return the html block.

Why is that? What exactly does `wp_reset_query()` do in this situation? Does it unset some variable or destroy my post object, which the theme might check to decide wether to display the comments section? I checked the wordpress codex and it explicitly [states the folowing](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage):

> Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset with wp_reset_query()

The theme is professional-grade and as far as I can tell rather well written, so I don't think it's just a bug in the theme, but rather some functionality or interaction I'm missing (which is why I ask this here and not in the theme support forums) ...

Comment: Are you using the loop on your `$posts` object? `wp_reset_query` also calls [`wp_reset_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: @Milo I'm iterating over my $posts object in this way: `while($posts->have_posts()){ $posts->the_post(); $html = '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>'; }` The actual html code is longer of course, but you get the point. So when wp_reset_postdata is called, it reset the current post from the last post in my $posts object to the page itself, and this is why the theme doesn't render the comments block anymore?